Dynamically concatenate columns in data frame in pipes
I have a process where I am merging dataframes together, and then generating an ID variable by concatenating some of the columns together. However, the names of the columns that need to be concatenated are in a character vector.
I can do this in separate steps like this:
new <- merge(old1, old2, by = "MergeVar")

id <- do.call(paste0, new[idcols])

new$id <- id

However, I'd like to do this using pipes. If the columns were fixed, then I know I could do something like this:
new <- merge(old1, old2, by = "MergeVar") %>%
  mutate(id = paste0(colA, colB))

Is there a nice way to merge these two approaches together so that I can keep the pipe structure but reference the column names dynamically?

Can you provide some simple example data (as code, eg with dput()) so this question can be reproducible? That'd make it much easier for people to give relevant solutions.

I'll see what I can do, although I'm working in an environment that makes it hard to extract data and code.

merge(old1, old2, by = "MergeVar") %>% mutate(id = do.call(paste0, pick(all_of(idcols)))) should work.  But Jon is right, it's better to make your issue reproducible so solutions can be tested.

Totally fine to include some simple made-up data, or use standard examples like dplyr::band_instruments and dplyr::band_members.

Assume the test data shown in the Note at the end.  BOD comes with R.
1) With base R we use merge and then create a list with a single x component holding the merge result and then use that in the last leg of the pipe.
old1 |>
  merge(old2, by = by_var) |>
  list(x = _) |>
  with(transform(x, id = do.call("paste0", x[idcols])))
##   Time demand.x demand.y       id
## 1    1      8.3      8.3   8.38.3
## 2    2     10.3     10.3 10.310.3
## 3    3     19.0     19.0     1919

2) With dplyr we can use left_join and use !! and !!! to insert the variables.
library(dplyr)

old1 %>%
  left_join(old2, join_by(!!sym(by_var))) %>%
  mutate(id = paste0(!!!syms(idcols)))
##   Time demand.x demand.y       id
## 1    1      8.3      8.3   8.38.3
## 2    2     10.3     10.3 10.310.3
## 3    3     19.0     19.0     1919

3) With magrittr but no other packages we can rewrite (1) as:
library(magrittr)

old1 %>%
  merge(old2, by = by_var) %>%
  transform(id = do.call("paste0", .[idcols]))
##   Time demand.x demand.y       id
## 1    1      8.3      8.3   8.38.3
## 2    2     10.3     10.3 10.310.3
## 3    3     19.0     19.0     1919

Note
old1 <- old2 <- head(BOD, 3)
by_var <- "Time"
idcols <- c("demand.x", "demand.y")

